# How do I use os.scandir() to return DirEntry objects recursively on a directory tree?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3.5's `os.scandir(path)` function returns lightweight DirEntry objects that are very helpful with information about files.  However, it only works for the immediate path handed to it.  Is there a way to wrap it in a recursive function so that it visits all subdirectories beneath the given path?

Comment: Take a look at [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.walk). It may be a bit more heavy-handed than your looking for, but it should be more simple than creating your own solution.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can scan recursively using `os.walk()`, or if you need `DirEntry` objects or more control, write a recursive function like `scantree()` below:

```
try:
    from os import scandir
except ImportError:
    from scandir import scandir  # use scandir PyPI module on Python < 3.5

def scantree(path):
    """Recursively yield DirEntry objects for given directory."""
    for entry in scandir(path):
        if entry.is_dir(follow_symlinks=False):
            yield from scantree(entry.path)  # see below for Python 2.x
        else:
            yield entry

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    for entry in scantree(sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'):
        print(entry.path)
```

Notes:

- There are a few more examples in [PEP 471](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/#examples) and in the [os.scandir() docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir).
- You can also add various logic in the for loop to skip directories or files starting with `'.'` and that kind of thing.
- You typically want `follow_symlinks=false` on the `is_dir()` calls in recursive functions like this, to avoid symlink loops.
- On Python 2.x, replace the `yield from` line with:

  ```
  for entry in scantree(entry.path):
      yield entry
  ```

Comment: Given that `os.scandir` only exists in Python 3.5, the Python 2 fallback code probably isn't needed. :-) __Edit:__ Ah, you wrote it to import the PyPI module if `os.scandir` didn't exist, and I'm guessing the PyPI module is available for 2.7?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Well, true, but this way it'll work for Python < 3.5 (including Python 2.x) using my [scandir](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scandir) module. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger I've added a code comment to clarify.

Comment: you're the author of the backport! congrats it's a life saver

Comment: os.walk vs os.scandir -- I ran these 2 functions against a directory with over 4 million directories and files.  os.walk took 34 min, 29 sec and os.scandir took 7 minutes, 46 sec. So, at least for my test, it appears os.scandir is about 4 1/2 times faster.

Comment: The [**`scandir`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) documentation also recommends using a context manager, i.e. `with scandir(path) as entries:`

Comment: It's worth noting that as a part of PEP 471 os.walk was updated to use os.scandir under the hood.